# Drupal views: bring nodes with taxonomy term X to top

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a simple view of fields (drupal 9) that lists nodes from a single content type (client). A node has a taxonomy reference field (field_client_country) where an editor can add the country or countries the client is from.

I need to extend the view so that nodes with, for example 'Italy', are brought to the top of the listing. After that, all the other nodes can be displayed.

How is this possible in views? I think i need to be in views_query_alter hook, but whatever i try it doesn't work.

```
function module_sticky_clients_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)
{

    $id = $view->id();
    $country_ids = ['312', '112']; //IT-italy, then NL-netherlands

    if ($id == 'view_clients') {

        //bring nodes with $country_ids to top of listing, then show the rest

    }

}
```

Comment: It may be easier to sort them after they have been retrived from the database but before they are displayed. Maybe via a preprocess hook.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could set the order of the taxonomy terms directly in the taxonomy UI, then add the taxonomy term weight to the view and order by that.

Comment: @2pha thx for your proposals... Preprocessing the results seems not possible since the view is paged (15 items per page, 22 pages in total). I only have access to the result data per page. Your second solution: sorting by taxonomy term weight, by adding a relationship gives me duplicate results (since you can add multiple countries to a client). Setting the query option to 'Distinct' will not remove the duplicates.

Comment: Rather than 'Distinct', try using aggregation on the view and grouping by the nid.

Comment: I might be missing something, but can't you just add a filter on the taxonomy term reference field to the view?

Comment: Adding filters limits the results to the selected nodes with term x. I need a list of nodes that have term x to be the first items in the list, not filter the others out.

Comment: kevinius, if the page was always use "Italy" from your example then you can just use the built in attachments functionality in Views without any code.  Glad to tell you more about this if you think this will work.

Comment: @Josh, i like your attachment option, please tell me more. I think this can work...

Comment: @kevinius, this looks like a good article to checkout https://www.drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/07/using-views-relationships-arguments-and-attachments?page=1